# unicode code table combination to support most languages

Tags: unicode, multilingual, fonts

I just coded the first version of an efficient glyph-to-texture function which takes ranges of unicode characters to store into one or more pov2 textures and am searching for information regarding which code charts are used in which language. I know that the Unicode Consortium gives this per glyph, but that would take really long to check out on my own.

I'd like to support as many of European languages, Cyrillic not a necessity

Edit: I can use every Latin chart, but I would like to save space with removing some extended charts such as Latin extended-D. I'm pretty sure that the only ext. I need to represent every character in my languages alphabet (Slovenian) is Latin-1 + Latin EXTENDED A, so I save ~600 characters

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out about some [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Glyph_List_4#See_also).

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://tools.scarfboy.com/unicode.html) might be helpful. Scroll down to the bottom for a list of codepoint ranges.

Comment: this is the same as http://www.unicode.org/charts/ which doesn't answer my question + edited question